# randomized algorithm and one solved example in probability

Tags: probability, computer-science

Example: a randomized algorithm was given and role of it, is to determines whether an input $a$ is a prime number?

This algorithm works in the following manner for one step:

> I- If $a$ is prime, then our algorithm outputs **YES**
>
> II- If $a$ is not prime, then our algorithm outputs **NO** with the probability $\frac{3}{4}$.

if we want to guarantee that achieve an output **NO** with the probability at least $1- \frac{1}{k}$ on step **II**, we should run this algorithm at least $O(\log k)$ times.

**Note:** first **NO** answer implies that a given input $a$ is not prime.

How this example solved? i.e: how $O(\log k)$ is determined?

**Update:**

we know the probability to tell **yes** in $x$ repeats of the algorithm on step II is $(\frac{1}{4})^x = 4^{-x} = 2^{-2x}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: What's the probability that it answers "yes" $n$ times for some composite $a$?

Comment: Can you clarify whether the guarantee is conditional on the input being a composite (i.e. a NO instance of the problem)? If it is a prime (i.e. a YES instance) then there is no way to guarantee an output of NO.

Comment: That's right.  So the probability that it answers "no" at least once is $1-\left(\frac14\right)^x$ and we want this to be $\geq1-\frac1k$.  Can you finish it?

Comment: @MK You're halfway there. How does saulspatz's hint relate to achieving a **NO**? And how does that relate to the desired probability $1 - 1/k$? Can you set up a solvable *inequality*?

Comment: @MK You can equate, but it's better to do as saulspatz suggested, $1 - 1/k \leq 1 - (1/4)^x$. Can you solve for $x$? Hint: You'll want to take the logarithm (the base is immaterial asymptotically) at some point. Also recall what $x$ is! Do you see how solving for it solves the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that the probability that it incorrectly answers "yes" on some composite in $n$ trials of the algorithm is $\left(\frac14\right)^n$ so the probability that it answers "no" at least once in $n$ runs is $1-\left(\frac14\right)^n$.  Thus, we want to find $n$ such that $$1-\left(\frac14\right)^n\geq1-\frac1k$$ or $$\frac1k\geq\left(\frac14\right)^n$$  Taking logarithms, $$-\log k\geq -n\log4$$ or $$n\geq \frac{\log k}{\log4}=O(\log k)$$

Comment: There's no way to ensure that the probability is exactly $1-\frac1k$, because $n$ has to be an integer.  All we can do is ensure that it is at least that great.

Comment: @MK Yes, that's right.

Comment: please clean all comments thanks so much.